# UITableView, delete buttons

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In an iPhone app. I would like to implement a feature to allow the user to delete a section in a **UITableView**.
For that I would like to use the same buttons as those used by default to delete a **UITableViewCell**.

Hoping I do not need to re-draw them.

How can I get those buttons, if possible pro-grammatically?

Thanks for any tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I need to replicate Apple created controls, usually I just search for the images Apple is using. To do that I use UIKit image extractor and look for the resource I am interedted in

https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor

Comment: Thanks a lot I did know that.